# Why is an array with const length considered to be a variable-sized object by the compiler?

Tags: arrays, initialization, constants, c89

In C, variable-size arrays cannot be initialized, i.e.,

```
int size = 3;
int array[size] = {1, 2, 3}; /* error: variable-sized object may not be initialized */
```

We can define `size` as a pre-processor macro to make it work:

```
#define size (3)
int array[size] = {1, 2, 3}; /* works */
```

I'd prefer to use constants instead of macro, so I'd like to do:

```
const int size = 3;
int array[size] = {1, 2, 3}; /* error: variable-sized object may not be initialized */
```

**Question:** Why does this last variant not work? if `const` is telling the compiler that I have no intentions of modifying the variable, why doesn't it deduce that the array isn't variable-sized?

I also tried to make `size` static, to no avail:

```
static const int size = 3;
int array[size] = {1, 2, 3}; /* error: variable-sized object may not be initialized */
```

**Note:** I know that I could just do

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

However, `size` is later used to iterate over the array so I'd like the compiler to throw a warning if`size` does not match the actual size of the array.

Comment: This is not a standard C89 construct, is it ? What's the compiler ?

Comment: Which construct are you refering to? Everything compiles (with the indicated errors) using gcc-3.4.4 with std=C89 (except for the //-style comments, which I fixed)

Comment: "Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++."

Comment: You can use `int array[] = {1, 2, 3}; int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);` in C89

Comment: True, although `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is probably better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why neither a variable of type `const int` nor `const static int` can be used to declare an array: The array size needs to be a constant expression. In C, a constant expression is something like a literal constant or a `sizeof` expression (the latter only since C99), BUT NOT a `const` variable. Curiously, in C++ a `const` variable is a constant expression and can be used to declare an array.

Answer (score 0):

[Gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) says

> The storage is allocated at the point of declaration

for variable-sized arrays.

For an array to be initialized, its storage has to be allocated at compile time.

It is the optimizer that turns a const variable into a constant. But in order for a program to be optimized, it needs to be valid at first.